# Warning message in IAsyncEnumerable when it lacks the await operator

Tags: c#, async-await, iasyncenumerable

When calling a method like this without doing an `await` task, we can return the following:

```
public Task<bool> GetBoolAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

What would be the equivalent for a `IAsyncEnumerable<>` and avoid the warning.

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GetBoolsAsync() // <- Ugly warning
{
    yield return true;
    yield break;
}
```

> Warning   CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Comment: Why is your method async if it does not use await? That's what the warning means.

Comment: Do you intend to do anything asynchronous in that method?

Comment: It's matching an interface. Other classes will have it async.

Comment: Then fine, don't pay attention to the warning.

Comment: There's no need to ignore the warnings here - the code can easily be written warning-free, as per my answer. (It's been downvoted for no obvious reason, but the other answers have been downvoted too. The code definitely works.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, ignoring a warning is not the way to go. Both original answers are valid, but one is just too verbose. I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would probably write a *synchronous* iterator method, then use `ToAsyncEnumerable` from the [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) package to convert it to the async version. Here's a complete example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await foreach (bool x in GetBoolsAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    // Method to return an IAsyncEnumerable<T>. It doesn't
    // need the async modifier.
    static IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GetBoolsAsync() =>
        GetBools().ToAsyncEnumerable();

    // Regular synchronous iterator method.
    static IEnumerable<bool> GetBools()
    {
        yield return true;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

This complies with the interface (of using `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`) but allows a synchronous implementation, with no warnings. Note that the `async` modifier itself is *not* part of a method signature - it's an implementation detail. So a method specified in an interface as returning a `Task<T>`, `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` or whatever can be implemented with an async method, but doesn't have to be.

Of course for a simple example where you just want to return a single element, you could use `ToAsyncEnumerable` on an array, or the result of `Enumerable.Repeat`. For example:

```cs
static IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GetBoolsAsync() =>
    new[] { true }.ToAsyncEnumerable();
```

Comment: This works great, except with EF Core 3... I get plenty of ambiguous calls. https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1057

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `TaskCompletionSource`.  This gives you the most flexibility.  You can set exceptions on the task, mark it incomplete etc.  Alternatively `Task.FromResult`.

> In many scenarios, it is useful to enable a Task to represent
>   an external asynchronous operation. TaskCompletionSource is
>   provided for this purpose. It enables the creation of a task that can
>   be handed out to consumers. The consumers can use the members of the
>   task the same way as they would in any other scenario handling task
>   member variables.

Consider the following options for both, I include the first, but you can't return a `Task.CompletedTask<T>`, but if you just want to return a completed Task, eg cause maybe you had some `out` parameters that have been set, then that might be your answer.

```
    static async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

or - because we can't use await without async

```
    static Task<bool> SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        taskSource.SetResult(true);
        return taskSource.Task;
    }
```

or (.Net 4.5+)

```
   static Task<bool> SomeEvenOtherMethod()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

or the async variant of the above

```
    static async Task<bool> SomeEvenOtherMethod()
    {
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        taskSource.SetResult(true);
        return (await taskSource.Task);
    }
```

Alternatively: (.Net 4.5+)

```
    static async Task<bool> SomeEvenOtherMethod()
    {
        return(await Task.FromResult(true));
    }
```

And with an IAsyncEnumerable

```
    static async IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GetBoolsAsync()
    {
        var t = await SomeOtherMethod();
        yield return t;
    }
```

Or (.Net 4.5+)

```
    static async IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GetBoolsAsync() 
    {
        yield return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

Comment: I think your solution is acceptable, however, I usually don't have an await in my `return Task.FromResult(true);`. I was not aware of the `TaskCompletionSource`, if I mix it with my `IAsyncEnumerable`, I wouldn't call `SomeOtherMethod()` but copy the idea of `TaskCompletionSource` inside my `IAsyncEnumerable`. It works, but it's super verbose to remove a warning. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes it is a but of a mouthful pre 4.5.  I assume your'e aware that you can turn off the warning globally or even per Method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning